# PHP fails on launch

Tags: php, xampp, startup

I recently asked a question at [Can't run PHP after a new installation of XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828593/cant-run-php-after-a-new-installation-of-xampp) but now I realise that I was wrongly blaming a new installation of XAMPP. I've now got the same problem on two computers with different versions of XAMPP, so the problem must be somewhere in my coding, but I can't find it.

XAMPP starts up OK with Apache and MySQL. But then running the simplest PHP script...
    `<?php echo "HELLO"; ?>`
produces these error messages...

Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'F:/My Documents/OneDrive/Webs/htdocs/phpinfo.php' (include_path='.;C:/xampp/php/pear/PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

That path to PEAR is specified in php.ini and it DOES exist. I can change php.ini to show any include_path and it doesn't matter whether it exists or not, the same error message appears (showing whatever include_path I have put in).

Even phpinfo.php will not run, as shown in the above example, although phpMyAdmin runs OK.

I'm now convinced that my two XAMPP installations on two computers cannot be causing this, but the error messages are not helping me find the problem. I now have to develop code on remote hosts to get around this problem. Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your phpinfo file should be on your local host folder, that if you installed xampp as default, should be on c:/xampp/htdocs

Comment: Also if you wont use pear u would clean the include path as it is not necessary

Comment: why your phpinfo is on OneDrive?

Comment: Thanks to all who commented.

Comment: To Gonzalo: I didn't install htdocs in the default folder. I've had it in OneDrive for years (successfully) so that it is available on two computers that I use for web development.

Comment: To jay: I don't use PEAR but it is installed. If I clear out the include_path then PHP adds its own default (from somewhere I don't know) which doesn't exist, and causes the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I directed my responses to the wrong people. Does anyone know where PHP gets a default include_path from when there's nothing in php.ini? And will that help? As I said, I'm getting the same type of error message regardless of whether the include_path exists or not.